# Distribution between $0$ and $n$ with closed for for expected value conditional on being greater than x.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm in the market for a distribution. Should be between $0$ and $n$. Preferably, but not necessarily over the integers. And most importantly, the expected value conditional on it being greater than $x$ should have a nice closed form. Does such a distribution exist? If we didn't need it to have an upper bound, we could have used the geometric distribution with its memory-less property.

Comment: There are too many distribtions satisfying this property. What about a uniform distribution over the integers $0$ to $n$? Or just choose $n$ with probability $1$? What shape do you want this distribution to have?

Comment: A very good point. I want it to have a mode and non-zero probabilities for all integers between $0$ and $n$.